# What is the meaning of "literally spruced up" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in Word by Word by Kory Stamper:

> Nowhere else is our institutional introversion borne out than at the Merriam- Webster holiday parties. The parties are usually held in the afternoon, in the basement of the building, which in some years is literally spruced up for the occasion.

I want to ask why the writer is emphasising "spruced up" with "literally". I mean what would "spruced up" metaphorically imply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross-post of the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217457/what-is-the-meaning-of-literally-spruced-up-in-this-sentence) that already has two answers.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence they are talking about a holiday party - so likely the 'literally spruced up' refers to the room being decorated by a Christmas tree,  which are commonly spruce trees.

> Christmas tree is a decorated tree, usually an evergreen conifer such
> as a **spruce,** pine or fir, or an artificial tree of similar appearance,
> associated with the celebration of Christmas, originating in Northern
> Europe

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree

To 'spruce up' is also an idiom, meaning to make clean or refined.  From thefreedictionary.com:

> **Spruce up**
>
> To make someone, something, or oneself more tidy, refined,
> elegant, or stylish. A noun or pronoun can be used between "spruce"
> and "up."

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spruce+up